# Spark Merge schema on write - getting error: "The column number of the existing table doesn't match the data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with Spark version 2.2.1 and trying to write new data to the existing table with additional column. Now I know already that it will not work, but I wonder what is the best workaround.

Here is a code example:

```
case class MyMockV1(a: String)
case class MyMockV2(a: String, b:String)

object StackOverflowSparkQuestion extends App{
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  sparkConf.setMaster(s"local[2]")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

  val values = List(MyMockV1("test1"), MyMockV1("test2"))
  val values2 = List(MyMockV2("test1","test2"), MyMockV2("test2","test3"))

  val tableName = "myTableTest"
  spark.createDataFrame(values).coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable(tableName)
  spark.createDataFrame(values2).coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable(tableName)


}
```

And I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: The column number of the existing table default.myTableTest(struct<a:string>) doesn't match the data schema(struct<a:string,b:string>);
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PreprocessTableCreation$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(rules.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PreprocessTableCreation$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(rules.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PreprocessTableCreation.apply(rules.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.PreprocessTableCreation.apply(rules.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
```

Currently I am planning to re-write my table, if someone has a better approach I will appreciate advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to add new column to existing table definition explicitly, before trying to write new data.

```
spark.sql("alter table myTableTest add columns (b string)")

spark.createDataFrame(values2).coalesce(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable(tableName)

spark.sql("select * from myTableTest").show(false)
+-----+-----+
|a    |b    |
+-----+-----+
|test1|test2|
|test2|test3|
|test1|null |
|test2|null |
+-----+-----+
```

For data that existed in the table before, new column values will appear as NULLs.